# Pi camera video stream to a PC (not through a web page) which has low latence

Tags: python, wifi, streaming-video, picamera

I need to send a video stream from my pi camera on a Raspberry pi to a computer on the same network. The video transmission should preferably have a low latency and a good image resolution. After the transmission the video stream has to be processed on the PC using Python. Therefore, the solutions I have found so far are out of the question (to a website or using VLC media player). Does anyone have a solution for my problem. I should also note that I can't get opencv installed on my Raspberry pi. For the last, I have already tried various options on the Internet. Does anyone know what the reason could be?

Comment: You seem to be asking two questions: we have a strict one question per question policy. Please edit. Ask another question if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

If you can pipe the camera to another process, then you can pipe it over the network.

To create a camera service on port 5000

```
«camera-process» | nc -l -p 5000
```

To connect to it

```
«viewer-process» < /dev/tcp/localhost/5000
```